# Incrementing variable multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose I have 10 threads that are incrementing a variable by 1. Suppose Thread-1 increments a variable first, and then Thread-2 and Thread-3 and consecutively. after all the 10 Threads have incremented the variable. I need to decrement the same variable in a manner.

Decrementing, if Thread-1 incremented the variable first of all, then it should decrement at last.

We need to do this without setting thread priority.

Comment: `Consecutively` not something you want use Multi threading for.

Comment: i know but i want to do it with multi-threading only.let's just say i have a requirement.

Comment: You can add some kind of shared logic which determine the order, ie a Class with an AtomicInteger, starting with value 1. All threads checking the value constantly where only the thread that equals that number (assign a number 1 to 10 to these threads) executes part 1 (increment). Then the AtomicInteger is incremented by one etc... When it reaches 10 the 10th thread executing part 2 (decrement) etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a lot of ways, here's one for example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            final int _i=i;
            Thread t = new Thread(new T(_i));
            t.start();
      }
    }
    public static class T implements Runnable{
        int threadNumber;
        public T(int threadNumber) {
            this.threadNumber=threadNumber;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            increase(this);
        }
    }
    static Thread[] threads = new Thread[10];
    static int number  =0;
    static Object generalLock=new Object();
    public static void increase(T t){
        int myNumber=0;
        synchronized (generalLock){
            myNumber=number;
            System.out.println("i am "+number+" incrementing, my real number "+t.threadNumber);
            threads[number]=Thread.currentThread();
            number++;
        }
        while (threads[9]==null){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        for(int i=9;i>myNumber;i--){
            try {
                threads[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        synchronized (generalLock){
            System.out.println("i am "+number+" decrementing, my real number "+t.threadNumber);
            number--;
        }
    }
}
```

output example:

```
i am 0 incrementing, my real number 1
i am 1 incrementing, my real number 8
i am 2 incrementing, my real number 9
i am 3 incrementing, my real number 7
i am 4 incrementing, my real number 6
i am 5 incrementing, my real number 5
i am 6 incrementing, my real number 0
i am 7 incrementing, my real number 4
i am 8 incrementing, my real number 3
i am 9 incrementing, my real number 2
i am 9 decrementing, my real number 2
i am 8 decrementing, my real number 3
i am 7 decrementing, my real number 4
i am 6 decrementing, my real number 0
i am 5 decrementing, my real number 5
i am 4 decrementing, my real number 6
i am 3 decrementing, my real number 7
i am 2 decrementing, my real number 9
i am 1 decrementing, my real number 8
i am 0 decrementing, my real number 1
```

Note: you can use simple Runnable, I create T class to show the thread number in order to print it while   incrementing/decrementing

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work. Essentially I create the `10` threads and specially identify one of them using an `enum`. They all try to increment the shared integer, identifying themselves. The incrementer detects the first increment by noticing the transition to `1` and if it's a `Special` thread it returns `true` .

There's also a `CountDownLatch` used to synchronise all of the threads to ensure there is at least a chance of the two alternatives. I get about `8600` out of the `10000` test runs where the `Special` got there first. This value will vary depending on many variables.

```
enum Who {
    Special, Normal;
}

class PriorityIncrementer {
    final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);

    boolean inc(Who who) {
        return i.incrementAndGet() == 1 && who == Who.Special;
    }

    public void dec() {
        i.decrementAndGet();
    }
}

class TestRunnable implements Runnable {
    final Who me;
    final PriorityIncrementer incrementer;
    final CountDownLatch latch;

    public TestRunnable(PriorityIncrementer incrementer, CountDownLatch latch, Who me) {
        this.incrementer = incrementer;
        this.latch = latch;
        this.me = me;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Wait for all others to get here.
        latch.countDown();
        try {
            // Wait here until everyone os waiting here.
            latch.await();
            // Do it.
            if(incrementer.inc(me)) {
                // I was first and special, decrement after.
                incrementer.dec();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private boolean test(int count) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[count];
    // The shared incrementer.
    PriorityIncrementer incrementer = new PriorityIncrementer();
    // Arrange for all of them to synchronise.
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(threads.length+1);
    // One special.
    threads[0] = new Thread(new TestRunnable(incrementer, latch, Who.Special));
    // The rest are normal.
    for(int i = 1; i < threads.length; i++) {
        threads[i] = new Thread(new TestRunnable(incrementer, latch, Who.Normal));
    }
    // Start them up.
    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        thread.start();
    }
    // Wait a moment.
    Thread.sleep(1);
    // Start them all going.
    latch.countDown();
    // Wait for them to finish.
    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
    // Who won?
    return incrementer.i.get() < count;
}

public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    final int tests = 10000;
    int specialWasFirstCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++) {
        if(test(10)) {
            specialWasFirstCount += 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Specials: "+specialWasFirstCount+"/"+tests);
}
```